# Connecting different tables to different items in combo box in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox

Good afternoon all,

I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this. I am currently working on a project and I am using an Access file as a database. I am trying to figure out how to populate items in my combobox from the different tables I have inside of my access database. I am using C# and Access 2016. I have tried to use some other examples and found that I am not looking in the right direction.

Edit:
I may have been a bit vague in this question. I have around 7 tables all with different names "ESC,AJJH,etc."  in a Access file and I need to have the table names populate my combobox so when the user selects the combo box they can manipulate the data that's within the selected table. I hope this is more clear, I apologize if not.

Thank you!

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var connection = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString =
                @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\grosales\Documents\rhg\RHG\Used.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password = MyDbPassword;";

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string query = "select * from Tables";
                command.CommandText = query;

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    schoolcombo.Items.Add(reader);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: these tables have more than one column right?...i dont think a combobox is the right choice of control...more like a datagridview

Comment: They can only add data by clicking a simple button. It's basically a generator that creates hex codes and doesn't repeat itself. Different schools require a different first digit so I figured it would be easier to use an access database and just add data into the fields based on what school they are at

Comment: access is evil...you should burn whatever machine it was installed on...and then salt the earth that the machine is on so another access install does not grow

Comment: Lol access isn't that bad

Comment: id recommend a listbox if its single column instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DbConnection. GetSchema to get  the list of tables.

[display the list of tables in access database using c#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/07caf03e-8aaa-4075-b1c3-cd82b38b93b8/display-the-list-of-tables-in-access-database-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: I’m going to give this a shot. Thank you!

Comment: Do not forget to evaluate if the link is useful @G.Rose

Comment: Got it! the only thing is that when you create the Data table named "table" or whatever else, dataRow is no longer used in C#. You replace the "dataRow" in his code with the name of your Data table and it will work

Answer (score 0):

It is not so clear what you want. But supposing that your tables have the same kind of columns. You could make use of UNION statement:

```
string query = "select field1, field2 from Table1 UNION select field1, field2 from Table2"; //AND SO ON
```

Comment: Sorry not sure how to word it properly. I have multiple tables called "ajjh, esc, hbr, support, etc." and I want to have the names of the each table populate the items in my combobox named "schoolcombo". I am writing a program that will need to be able to read,write, and check whatever table is selected for duplicate hexadecimals